# Change embedded google map satellite view to street view

Tags: php, html, google-maps

I have a google map that is embedded in my website, unfortunately it is in satellite view like this.

```html
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d579.4542453260605!2d120.96262496097803!3d14.687714819878153!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0000000000000000%3A0x827322d8f7559441!2sTriune+Electronics+Systems!5e1!3m2!1sen!2sph!4v1436755310929" width="800" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
                        </div>
```

What I want to do is to change it from satellite view to street view for a much more clean looked.

**Edit:** While writing down my question I notice of the answer so I guessed I should also write it here.

**Edit** Looks like I'm also a little confused about the definition of those 2 kinds of maps. I'm looking for this kind of map

[image]

Not this one

[image]

I'm really confused about the definition, what do we call those 2 maps?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed

Comment: You want "StreetView" or a ["ROADMAP"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeId)?

Comment: Read the tag-descriptions before adding!

Comment: See my edit here please.